Estimating the parameters of an ellipse (part 2)
This post is a follow up of this previous one. I would like to clarify why the angle estimator works and how to estimate the axes length. Unfortunately, I still have some trouble with this problem. I will give a brief discussion before stating my question.
I will use $'$ to denote the transpose operator and I will implicitly use the following properties of the rotation matrix $R$ and the diagonal matrix $D$
\begin{equation*}
R' = R^{-1} \qquad
D' = D
\end{equation*}
From "natural" representation to quadratic representation
An ellipse $\mathcal{E}(\ell_1,\ell_2,\theta)$ can be seen as linear transformation of a circle with unitary radius, i.e. given the unit circle
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{C} \triangleq \{\tilde{p}\in \mathbb{R}^2: \tilde{p}'\tilde{p}=1\}
\end{equation*}
the ellipse with (semi) axes $\ell_1,\ell_2$ and orientation $\theta$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{E}(\ell_1,\ell_2,\theta) =\{p=A\,\tilde{p}\}_{\tilde{p}\in \mathcal{C}}
\end{equation*}
where the transformation matrix is
\begin{equation*}
A(\ell_1,\ell_2,\theta)\triangleq \underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{array}\right]}_{\text{rotation } R}
\underbrace{\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\ell_1 & 0 \\
0 & \ell_2\end{array}\right]}_{\text{dilation } D}
\end{equation*}
Since $\tilde{p}=A^{-1} p$, it follows  from the Cartesian equation of the unit circle that the Cartesian equation of the ellipse is
\begin{equation*}
(A^{-1}p)'(A^{-1}p)=1 \qquad \equiv \qquad p'\,\underbrace{(AA')^{-1}}_{\triangleq X}\,p =1
\end{equation*}
Beside the three scalars $\ell_1,\ell_2, \theta$, the matrix $X$ provides an equivalent method identify the ellipse, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{E}(X) =\{p\in \mathbb{R}^2: p'\,X\,p=1\}
\end{equation*}
Note that $X$ has to be symmetric and positive definite (SPD) because it comes from the product $AA'$. Moreover, due to its definition as $(AA')^{-1}$, has the following special structure
\begin{equation}
X= R\,\Lambda^{-1} R'
\tag{$\star$}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation*}
\Lambda^{-1} \triangleq D^{-1}\,D^{-1} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}
1/\ell_1^{2} & 0 \\
0            & 1/\ell_2^2
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
From quadratic representation to "natural" representation
Given a SPD matrix $X$, the "natural" parameters $\ell_1,\ell_2, \theta$ can be retrieved by just a simple diagonalization. Indeed, due to $(\star)$, the eigenvalues of $X$ are
\begin{equation*}
\lambda_{1,2}^{-1} \triangleq 1/\ell_{1,2}^2
\end{equation*}
and a couple of orthonormal eigenvectors is
\begin{equation*}
v_1 = \left[\begin{array}{c}
\cos \theta \\
\sin \theta
\end{array}\right] \qquad
v_2 = \left[\begin{array}{c}
-\sin \theta \\
\cos \theta
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation*}
Hence, given the factorization $(\Lambda^{-1}, R)$, the natural parameters can be retrieved from $X$ as
\begin{equation*}
\ell_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Lambda_{11}^{-1}}} \qquad
\ell_2 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Lambda_{22}^{-1}}} \qquad
\theta = \tan^{-1}(R_{21}/R_{11})
\end{equation*}
where $\Lambda_{ij}^{-1},R_{ij}$ are the $ij$-th entries of $\Lambda^{-1}$ and $R$.
Gaussian case
Consider a dataset $\{y_j\}_{j=1}^m$ where each observation follows the Gaussian distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma \triangleq X^{-1})$. As the sample covariance
\begin{equation*}S\triangleq \frac{1}{m-1} \sum_{j=1}^m (y_j-\bar{y})
(y_j-\bar{y})'\end{equation*}
estimates the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, a matrix estimate of the ellipse $X$ is given by the inverse sample covariance, i.e. we can consider the estimate $\hat{X}\triangleq S^{-1}$. Since $\hat{X}=\hat{R}\,\hat{\Lambda}^{-1}\,\hat{R}'$, it follows that diagonalizing the sample covariance $S$ gives
\begin{equation*}
S= (\hat{R}\,\hat{\Lambda}^{-1}\,\hat{R}')^{-1}= \hat{R}\,\hat{\Lambda}\,\hat{R}' 
\end{equation*}
and so, given the dataset $\{y_j\}_{j=1}^m$, we can estimate the parameters of the underlying ellipse as follows
\begin{equation*}
\hat{\ell}_1 \triangleq \sqrt{\hat{\Lambda}_{11}} \qquad
\hat{\ell}_2 \triangleq \sqrt{\hat{\Lambda}_{22}} \qquad
\hat{\theta} \triangleq \tan^{-1}(\hat{R}_{21}/\hat{R}_{11})
\end{equation*}
once computed the sample covariance $S$ and its diagonalization $(\hat{\Lambda}, \hat{R})$.
Uniform case 1
Consider a dataset $\{y_j\}_{j=1}^m$ where each observation is uniformly distributed over the ellipse area, in short $y_j\sim \mathcal{U}(\mathcal{E}(\ell_1,\ell_2,\theta))$. It seems that the previous estimation formulas still work if the semi-axes estimates are scaled by a factor $2$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\hat{\ell}_1 \triangleq 2\sqrt{\hat{\Lambda}_{11}} \qquad
\hat{\ell}_2 \triangleq 2\sqrt{\hat{\Lambda}_{22}} \qquad
\hat{\theta} \triangleq \tan^{-1}(\hat{R}_{21}/\hat{R}_{11})
\tag{$\star\star$}
\end{equation}
Uniform case 2
Consider a dataset $\{y_j\}_{j=1}^m$ where each observation is uniformly distributed over the ellipse perimeter, in short $y_j\sim \mathcal{U}(\partial\mathcal{E}(\ell_1,\ell_2,\theta))$. It seems that the previous estimation formulas still work if the semi-axes estimates are scaled by a factor $\sqrt{2}$, i.e.
\begin{equation}
\hat{\ell}_1 \triangleq \sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{\hat{\Lambda}_{11}} \qquad
\hat{\ell}_2 \triangleq \sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{\hat{\Lambda}_{22}} \qquad
\hat{\theta} \triangleq \tan^{-1}(\hat{R}_{21}/\hat{R}_{11})
\tag{$\star\star\star$}
\end{equation}
Question

How do you prove (or disprove) that $(\star\star)$ and $(\star\star\star)$ are not unbiased?

